# How to compose figure from text with latex?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, listings

I have an ascii image like

```
+---------------
|  xxxxxxx
+---------------
|  xxxxxxx
+---------------
```

I want to show this in figure environment. So currently I try like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting{src.ascii}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{fig:xxx}
\end{figure}
```

which works, except for some subtlities with `table of listings` and `table of figures` settings. The above codes treat `src.ascii` as listing which counters my mind that `src.ascii` is, exactly, a figure.

I think I should either export the ascii file as an `eps` file or set `listing` package to omit some source input. How could I achieve it?

Thanks and Best regards.

---

A MWC

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting{xxx.ascii}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{fig:xxx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And an example ascii image:

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ?

Comment: @codebeard FYI.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to have "real" figures in LaTeX text, but if you insist on ASCII art (e.g. to show old-fashioned illustrations in RFCs), then the following works:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{verbatim}
 +-----------------+
 |                 |
 +-----------------+
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Box in an old RFC}
\label{fig:ascii-box}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: how to scale it? eg ascii art is too big

Comment: `{\tiny\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}}` will work

Comment: Yes, there is no need to embed it inside a figure

Answer (score 9):

As Boris mentioned, you can use `verbatim` which will not add anything to `\lstlistoflistings`, but if you still wanted to use the `listings` package for some reason (e.g. if you need more advanced formatting than provided by `verbatim`), just use the `nolol` (no list-of-listings) option:

```
\begin{figure}
    \lstinputlisting[nolol]{xxx.ascii}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{fig:xxx}
\end{figure}
```