# ASCII-Art Flower to a thesis in LaTex? How to make it nicely from front to back?

Tags: thesis

Thesis can have some sort of `thank you` thing in the beginning and perhaps something at the end. Instead of writing something specific, I would like to start a thesis with a flower-top and end it to its flower-end in ASCII art. I would like to make the flower from some lyrics in the following shape

[image]

so the reader would require almost a microscope to read the lyrics -- and it would be cool also to write something hovering in some point. Is this possible to do this kind of creative thing in LaTex and is there something already builtin to embed ASCII art to formal papers?

**Perhaps related**

1. [How to compose figure from text with latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62472/how-to-compose-figure-from-text-with-latex)

Comment: I would do this with PSTricks and `pst-text`.  Not really ASCII art, but in the same vein.  See [Text spirals with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88751),  [Shape driven formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105774) and [How to create roller coaster text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39223) for some ideas.

Comment: What did your final result look like? Can you share? :)

Comment: Where's David's Krampus when you need it? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149604/holiday-contest-drawing-a-picture-of-krampus-for-yule/149616#149616

Answer (score 19):

Why not just find your ASCII art by using an external package and include it verbatim, perhaps using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)'s `\lstinputlisting`:

[image]

`````````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,listings,graphicx,varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,listings,graphicx,varwidth}

% Source: http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/birds%20(water)
\begin{filecontents*}{duck.txt}
                                       .;;;..
                                    ;<!!!!!!!!;
                                 .;!!!!!!!!!!!!>
                               .<!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                              ;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
                            ;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
                           ;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!''
                         ,!!!!!!!!!!!!!'` .::
                  ,;!',;!!!!!!!!!!!'` .::::''  .,,,,.
                 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'`.::::' .,ndMMMMMMM,
                !!!!!!!!!!!!!' .::'' .,nMMP""',nn,`"MMbmnmn,.
                `!!!!!!!!!!` :'' ,unMMMM" xdMMMMMMMx`MMn
             _/  `'!!!!''`  ',udMMMMMM" nMMMMM??MMMM )MMMnur=
,.... ......--~   ,       ,nMMMMMMMMMMnMMP".,ccc, "M MMMMP' ,,
 `--......--   _.'        " MMP??4MMMMMP ,c$$$$$$$ ).MMMMnmMMM
     _.-' _..-~            =".,nmnMMMM .d$$$$$$$$$L MMMMMMMMMP
 .--~_.--~                  '.`"4MMMM  $$$$$$$$$$$',MMMMMPPMM
`~~~~                      ,$$$h.`MM   `?$$$$$$$$P dMMMP , P
                           <$""?$ `"     $$$$$$$$',MMMP c$
                           `$c c$h       $$$$$$$',MMMM  $$
                            $$ $$$       $$$$$$',MMMMM  `?
                            `$.`$$$c.   z$???"  "',,`"
                             3h $$$$$cccccccccc$$$$$$$$$$$=r
                             `$c`$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$??$$$$F"$$ "
                           ,mr`$c`$$$$$$$$$$$$$$c 3$$$$c$$
                        ,mMMMM."$.`?$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$h,
;.   .               .uMMMMMMMM "$c,`"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$C,,,,cccccc,,..
!!;,;!!!!> .,,...  ,nMMMMMMMMMMM.`?$c  `"?$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$h.
!!!!!!!!! uMM" <!!',dMMMMMMMMMMPP" ?$h.`::..`""???????""'..  -==cc,"?$$P
!!!!!!!!'.MMP <!',nMMMMMMMMP" .;    `$$c,`'::::::::::::'.$F
!!!!!!!! JMP ;! JMMMMMMMP" .;!!'      "?$hc,.````````'.,$$
!!!!'''' 4M(;',dMMMP""" ,!!!!` ;;!!;.   "?$$$$$?????????"
!!! ::. 4b ,MM" .::: !''`` <!!!!!!!!;
 `!::::.`' 4M':::::'',mdP <!!!!!!!!!!!;
! :::::: ..  :::::: ""'' <!!!!!!!!!!!!!!;
!! ::::::.::: .::::: ;!!> <!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!;.
!! :::::: `:'::::::!!' <!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!;;.
! ::::::' .::::' ;!' .!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'`!!!!!!!!!!!;.
; `::';!>  ::' ;<!.;!!!!!!!''''!!!!' <!! !!!!!!!!!!!>
\end{filecontents*}
\newsavebox{\asciiart}
\newcommand{\duck}{\raisebox{.8\height}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\usebox{\asciiart}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\asciiart}
\begin{varwidth}{\maxdimen}
\noindent\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{duck.txt}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}%

We love to see \duck{} duck.

\end{document}
`````````

Zooming in reveals...

[image]

There seems to be a number of [ASCII](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=TeX%20is%20awesome.) [generators](http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/) [out](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/) [there](http://www.degraeve.com/img2txt.php)...

Comment: A duck! Yes, yes, YES!!!! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

[image: ascii]

Each position corresponds to a pixel, with the character(s) at that position emulating a shade of gray.

For a fixed phrase, repeating, like "Happy Birthday", mapping from the ascii to a shade for each position is best done with lua code, or a regex.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}[Scale=0.5]

\newcommand\art{\fontsize{8pt}{0.4ex}\selectfont%
:~~~~~s~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,::,:~~~~~sssssssssss~~:::~::::,,,,,,,,,:::~ss\%\%\%s\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~~sssss~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,:,,:~~~~~sssssssss~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::~~sss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~ssssss~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:~~~~~sssss~~~~:,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::~~sss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~sssssss~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:~~~~~~~~~~::::,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::::::~~~~~ssssss~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

sssssss~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::~~::~~~::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::::::::~~::,,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~ssssss~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::~~~::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::::::::,::,:::::~~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~sssss~~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::~:~~::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,:::::::::::::::::,,::,,,:::::~~sssssssss~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~sss~~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::~~~~sss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

~~~~~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,:::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}sssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

:::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,,:,:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}ss\%\%\%sss\%\%\%\%\%\%s\%\%\%\%s:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}sss\%sssss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~~~sssO\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},,,::~O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%M\llap{X}\%\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}:::,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%s\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~:::,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%O\llap{/}sss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}~~~~~~::,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%s\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%s\%ssssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%:::~~~~~~::,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\%\%O\llap{/}ss\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssssss~sssss\%\%~~~~~~~~~~~~::,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}M\llap{X}\%ssM\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~,,,,,,,,,77M\llap{X}~\%M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:,,:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}sss\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}sss~ss~~sss\%s~sssss~~~~~~~~::,,,,

:,,,,,,,,......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}7M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}77M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:,:,,,,:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%sss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}sssss~~~ss\%~~~ssssss~~~~~~~~::,,,

::,,,,,,,.......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}7777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}7M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}:,,:,,,::::::::::::,:~\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssss~~~~s\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}~~~~~ssssss~~::,,,

:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}77777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}sO\llap{/}~:::::::::::::::::~\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssssss\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~ssssssss\%\%O\llap{/}:::~~~~~~:::,,,,

:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}::::::::::::::~s~s\%\%ssssssssssssss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}sssssssss\%\%O\llap{/}:::::::::,,,,,,

:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,::,\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}7777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:::::::::::~\%sss\%\%\%ss~sssssssssssss\%\%\%O\llap{/}ss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:::::,,,,,,,,,

:::,,,,,,......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::,\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}:::,:::::\%ss\%\%\%\%sss~:~sssssssssssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}::::,,,,,,,,,,

:::,,,,,,,..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}77M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}\%\%\%s\%O\llap{/}ssO\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:,:::::\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%s:::::~~~~ssssssssssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}::::::::::,,,

:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,M\llap{X}77777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%ss\%O\llap{/}\%M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}:~~~~O\llap{/}~~~~:::::~:,:~:sssssss\%O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssssssss~~:,,

:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,,,,,:7777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%ssssssO\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}ss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}ss\%ssssss~~~~:::~~:,sssssss\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%ssss~~:,

:::,,,,,,,,,,,,::~s~~~:::O\llap{/}7777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%sssss\%M\llap{X}O\llap{/}s\%\%s~sss\%O\llap{/}\%ssss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}\%ssssss~:~~~~:,,,,~,O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%ssss~

:::,,,,,,,:~sss~s~~~~~~~7777777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%sssss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%ss\%\%~~ss\%O\llap{/}ssss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%ssssss:~ss~~::,,,::,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%sssssssssssssss

:::,,,,,,~ss~~~~~~~~~~~:s777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%sssss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}ss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%~~s\%ss\%sss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%s~ssss::\%sss~~:,,,,~,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%::::::::~~~~~~::

:::,,,:ss\%\%\%\%\%ss~sssss~:O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%sssss\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}s\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~\%\%ss~sss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%~~~~~::sssss~~:::::::::::,,,,,,~M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%::::::::::::::,,,

:::,,,:s\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}\%ss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%ssss\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%s~\%s~\%~~~ss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%~~~~~:~~ss~~:::~~~~~~~~::::,,,,,:O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}\%:,::::::::::,,,,,,,

::,,,::::~s\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}\%\%\%M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}sss\%\%\%O\llap{/}s\%O\llap{/}s\%\%\%\%sss\%s~s~s~ssO\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%sss~~::sss~::~~~~ssssssss~~::,,,,,,:,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,

,:,,,:::::~~~~O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%ss\%O\llap{/}7ss\%\%\%\%s\%\%ssssssssss\%s\%~~ss\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%~sss~:~~s~:::~ssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%ss~~:,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,

:::,,,,::~~~~~sO\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}77M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%ss\%\%O\llap{/}7ss\%\%sss\%ss\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}s~~~s\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%~~~ss::ss~::::~ss\%sss\%s\%\%sss~~::::::,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,

::::,,,,,,,,::::~s\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}777M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%ss\%\%\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}ss\%sss\%ssssssss\%sss~ss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%,:~s~:~s\%~:::~\%\%\%\%sssssss~~~::~~~~~~~~:::,,,,:::::::::,,,,

:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~s\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}\%\%sss~\%\%\%\%M\llap{X}\%\%O\llap{/}ss\%ssssssssss~~sss\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X},,:~::sss~::~\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%ssss~~::::,,::~~~~~~~~~~~::,::::::::::::,

,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%sss~s\%\%\%M\llap{X}M\llap{X}ss\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%s~~ssss\%O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X},,::~\%\%s::s\%O\llap{/}\%ss\%\%\%~:,,,,,,,,,:::::~~~~~~~::,,,:::::::::~

,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%sss~sssM\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}~\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~O\llap{/}\%\%ssssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},:~:~\%\%s:s\%\%\%s~ss~:,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::,,,,::,,,,::~

,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,sO\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}\%\%\%sssssssssO\llap{/}O\llap{/}s~sssssssssss\%ssss\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},,::~ss~s\%\%s~~::::,,,,,::::~~~~~:::,,,,,,:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:sO\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%ssssssssssO\llap{/}\%ss~sssssssssssss\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}:,::ss~~~~::::::::::,,:::~~~~~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%sssss~~sssO\llap{/}O\llap{/}ssss~sssss\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~::~ss::,,:::::::::::::::::~~~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,sss\%\%\%s~~~ssssssss\%sssssss\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~::~~:,:::~~~~s~~~::,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\%ssss~ssssssssss~ssssss\%sss\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X},,~~:::,,::::::~~:,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~\%\%\%sssssssssssss~ssss\%sss\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}O\llap{/}M\llap{X}\%~:~~:,,,:::,,,,,::~~:,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%ssssssssssss~~s\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}M\llap{X}~sO\llap{/}::~~~~,:~:,,,,,,,,,,:~:,,,,,,::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%sssssssss~~~~~~\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}~~s~sss\%ssss~~~~~~:~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s\%ssssssssssss~~:~~~~~:~::::::~~~~~~s,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%sssss\%sss:::~~~~~~sssssss~~~~s~,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%\%s:,::~~sssssss~~~~~~~ss:::::,,,,,,,::~ssss~~~:::,,,,,,,,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%\%\%sss,,::~~~~~~~~~~s~~~~s::::~~::,,,::~~sssss~~~::::,,,,:::~~~~~:,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%~sss~~~:::::~~~~ss~~~~~::::~~~::,,::~~~~~~ss~~~:::::,:::~~~sss~:,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}:::~::~s~:~~~~s~~~~~~~~~::::::::,,:~~ss~~s~sss~~~::::::::::~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~\%O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}\%,s:,,s~:~s\%s::~~~~~~~~~:,:::::::::::~sssssssssss~~~::~:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/}O\llap{/},,,,,,,,,~ssssss::~~::~~~,,,,,:::::::~~sssssss~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,..

,,,,,,,,:::::~~~:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~O\llap{/}\%\%\%::,,,,,,,,,::s~ssssss:::::s,,,,:::::::::::~~~~~~:::::::::::::::~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,::~~~~~sssss~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,:,:~s~~s~~sss~:~:::~~::::::~~~~:::::::,,,,:::::::::::~~~:::,,,,,,,:~~:,,.

,,,,,,:::~~ssssssssssss~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~:::~:::~~~~:~~~~~~~:::~~~~~::::::,:::::::::::::~~~~::,,....,,:~~~~:
}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\art
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183447/how-compose-an-image-from-a-specific-text

Answer (score 2):

Adapting and slightly extending izabera's answer on texSE from 2014 ([How compose an image from a specific text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183447/how-compose-an-image-from-a-specific-text)), if we start with a portable grayscale map (.pgm) file

[image: pgm file]

the original solution code produces this

[image: mapped grayscale]

With the extended commands, the whole picture can be shaded text

[image: whole picture]

or the lighter parts only

[image: lighter parts]

or the darker parts only

[image: darker parts]

In terms of text shape, with normal monochrome text, the lighter shade areas can be filled in

[image: shaped text]

or the darker shade areas

[image: shaped text negative]

MWE

```
%Adapting and slightly extending izabera's answer on texSE from 2014:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183447/how-compose-an-image-from-a-specific-text

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\directlua {require "asciiart3"}
\newcommand\bwasciitextshape[5]{\directlua{bwasciitextshape("#1",#2,#3,#4,[[#5]])}}
\newcommand\bwasciitextshade[5]{\directlua{bwasciitextshade("#1",#2,#3,#4,[[#5]])}}
\newcommand\bwascii[1]{\directlua{bwascii("#1")}}
\newcommand\colorascii[1]{\directlua{colorascii("#1")}}
\newcommand\bwframe[1]{\vspace*{\fill}\bwascii{#1}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}
\newcommand\colorframe[1]{\vspace*{\fill}\colorascii{#1}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\fbox{\includegraphics{flower1.png}}\\
Bermuda buttercup \\
Wikipedia: ``flower'' \\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
$\mapsto$
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{c}
\fbox{\includegraphics{flower1gs.png}}\\
grayscale \\
 \\
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\ttfamily\frenchspacing
\newlength{\correctem}\settowidth{\correctem}{M}%to set the size of the minipage
\newlength{\correctex}\settowidth{\correctex}{x}%to set the line height
\pagestyle{empty}\centering


%----------------------------------------------------
%\bwasciitextshade{flower1.pgm}{1}{0}{256}{A flower, ...}
%\bwasciitextshade{A}              {B}{C}{D}  {E}
%               A = image filename
%                               portable gray map format (.pgm) 
%                                       create .pgm fle with, e.g., ImageMagick:
%magick convert -compress none -resize 50% flower1.png flower1.pgm
%               B = line spacing scaling factor
%                               1: aspect-ratio of image kept, but text is close together
%                               <1: squash image vertically (e.g., 0.8)
%                               >1: stretch image vertically (e.g., 1.2): easier to read text
%               C = from-value, grayscale
%                               integer, 0 (darkest) to 255 (lightest)
%               D = to-value, grayscale
%                               integer, 0 (darkest) to 255 (lightest) 
%               E = text
%----------------------------------------------------


ascii art: \textbackslash bwasciitextshade: full picture filled with matching multi-shaded text\par(text from Wikipedia: "flower")

\fbox{%
\bwasciitextshade{flower1.pgm}{1}{0}{256}{A flower, sometimes known as a bloom or blossom, is the reproductive structure found in flowering plants (plants of the division Magnoliophyta, also called angiosperms). The biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing (fusion of sperm and eggs from different individuals in a population) resulting from cross pollination or allow selfing (fusion of sperm and egg from the same flower) when self-pollination occurs. }
}
\newpage
ascii art: \textbackslash bwasciitextshade: light-shaded shapes filled with matching multi-shaded text

\fbox{%
\bwasciitextshade{flower1.pgm}{1}{170}{256}{A flower, sometimes known as a bloom or blossom, is the reproductive structure found in flowering plants (plants of the division Magnoliophyta, also called angiosperms). The biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing (fusion of sperm and eggs from different individuals in a population) resulting from cross pollination or allow selfing (fusion of sperm and egg from the same flower) when self-pollination occurs. }
}
\newpage
ascii art: \textbackslash bwasciitextshade: dark-shaded shapes filled with matching multi-shaded text

\fbox{%
\bwasciitextshade{flower1.pgm}{1}{0}{170}{A flower, sometimes known as a bloom or blossom, is the reproductive structure found in flowering plants (plants of the division Magnoliophyta, also called angiosperms). The biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing (fusion of sperm and eggs from different individuals in a population) resulting from cross pollination or allow selfing (fusion of sperm and egg from the same flower) when self-pollination occurs. }
}
\newpage
ascii art: \textbackslash bwasciitextshape: light-shaded shapes filled with normal-shade text

\fbox{%
\bwasciitextshape{flower1.pgm}{1}{170}{256}{A flower, sometimes known as a bloom or blossom, is the reproductive structure found in flowering plants (plants of the division Magnoliophyta, also called angiosperms). The biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing (fusion of sperm and eggs from different individuals in a population) resulting from cross pollination or allow selfing (fusion of sperm and egg from the same flower) when self-pollination occurs. }
}
\newpage
ascii art: \textbackslash bwasciitextshape: dark-shaded shapes filled with normal-shade text

\fbox{%
\bwasciitextshape{flower1.pgm}{1}{0}{170}{A flower, sometimes known as a bloom or blossom, is the reproductive structure found in flowering plants (plants of the division Magnoliophyta, also called angiosperms). The biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing (fusion of sperm and eggs from different individuals in a population) resulting from cross pollination or allow selfing (fusion of sperm and egg from the same flower) when self-pollination occurs. }
}
\newpage
ascii art: \textbackslash bwascii: 256-grayscale mapped to 8-scale text (\$,  B, Q, Y, v, \textasciitilde, ., \textvisiblespace)

\fbox{%
\bwascii{flower1.pgm}
}

\end{document}
```

asciiart3.lua

```
colorascii = function ( picture )
  -- read a picture in .ppm format
  local file = io.open(picture, "r")
  if file==nil then
    tex.sprint("file not found")
    return
  end
  local arr = {}
  for line in file:lines() do
    if line:sub(1,1)~="#" then--if line starts with # don't insert it
      table.insert(arr,line);
    end
  end
  file:close()
  if arr[1]~="P3" then
    tex.sprint("i don't like this file")
    --TODO: implement moar ways to detect if the file is corrupt
    return
  end
  local sizes = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(arr[2],"%d+") do
    table.insert(sizes,i)
  end
  local xsize = tonumber(sizes[1])
  local ysize = tonumber(sizes[2])
  table.remove(arr,1)--remove "P3"
  table.remove(arr,1)--remove sizes
  table.remove(arr,1)--remove maxval and assume no value is bigger than 255
  colors = ""
  for k,v in pairs(arr) do
    colors = colors..v.." "
  end
  colors = string.gsub(colors, " +", " ")
  --now all our picture is in a single string
  rgb = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(colors,"%d+ %d+ %d+") do
    temp = {}
    for j in string.gmatch(i, "%d+") do
      table.insert(temp,j)
    end
    table.insert(rgb, temp)
  end
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\resizebox{\\textwidth}{!}{")
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\begin{minipage}{"..xsize.."\\correctem}\\setlength\\baselineskip{1\\correctex}\\setlength\\lineskip{0pt}\\setlength\\prevdepth{0pt}")
  for i = 1,#rgb do
    tex.sprint("\\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{"..rgb[i][1]..","..rgb[i][2]..","..rgb[i][3].."}\\textcolor{mycolor}x\\hspace{0pt}")
  end
  tex.sprint("\\end{minipage}}")
end

valchar = function (val)--takes an integer from 0 to 255 and returns a character
  val = tonumber(val)
  valuetable = {"\\$","B","Q","Y","v","~","."," "}--return darker characters for darker values
  return valuetable[math.floor(val/32)+1]
end


bwasciitextshade = function ( picture, bsl, thresholda, thresholdb, mystring )
  local file = io.open(picture, "r")
  if file==nil then
    tex.sprint("file not found")
    return
  end
  local arr = {}
  for line in file:lines() do
    if line:sub(1,1)~="#" then
      table.insert(arr,line);
    end
  end
  file:close()
  if arr[1]~="P2" then
    tex.sprint("i don't like this file")
    return
  end
  local sizes = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(arr[2],"%d+") do
    table.insert(sizes,i)
  end
  local xsize = tonumber(sizes[1])
  local ysize = tonumber(sizes[2])
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  greys = ""
  for k,v in pairs(arr) do
    greys = greys..v.." "
  end
  greys = string.gsub(greys, " +", " ")
  value = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(greys,"%d+") do
    table.insert(value, i)
  end
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\resizebox{\\textwidth}{!}{")
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\begin{minipage}{"..xsize.."\\correctem}\\setlength\\baselineskip{"..bsl.."\\correctex}\\setlength\\lineskip{0pt}\\setlength\\prevdepth{0pt}\\leavevmode")
  local letterarray = {}
    local targetStr = mystring
-- Looping through strings require gmatch.
    for c in string.gmatch(targetStr, ".") do 
      table.insert(letterarray, c)
    end 
 local i = 0
    local itemcount = 1
  for i = 1,#value do
        if (tonumber(value[i]) >  tonumber(thresholda)) and
             (tonumber(value[i]) <  tonumber(thresholdb)) then
--    tex.sprint("\\smash{"..valchar(value[i]).."}\\hspace{0pt}")
            if #letterarray > 0 then
    tex.sprint("\\color[gray]{"..(tonumber(value[i])/255).."}\\smash{"..letterarray[itemcount].."}\\hspace{0pt}")
    itemcount=itemcount+1
    if itemcount == #letterarray + 1 then
                itemcount = 1
    end
    end
    else
    tex.sprint("\\smash{".."\\ ".."}\\hspace{0pt}")
    end
  end
  tex.sprint("\\end{minipage}}")
end

--
bwasciitextshape = function ( picture, bsl, thresholda, thresholdb, mystring )
  local file = io.open(picture, "r")
  if file==nil then
    tex.sprint("file not found")
    return
  end
  local arr = {}
  for line in file:lines() do
    if line:sub(1,1)~="#" then
      table.insert(arr,line);
    end
  end
  file:close()
  if arr[1]~="P2" then
    tex.sprint("i don't like this file")
    return
  end
  local sizes = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(arr[2],"%d+") do
    table.insert(sizes,i)
  end
  local xsize = tonumber(sizes[1])
  local ysize = tonumber(sizes[2])
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  greys = ""
  for k,v in pairs(arr) do
    greys = greys..v.." "
  end
  greys = string.gsub(greys, " +", " ")
  value = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(greys,"%d+") do
    table.insert(value, i)
  end
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\resizebox{\\textwidth}{!}{")
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\begin{minipage}{"..xsize.."\\correctem}\\setlength\\baselineskip{"..bsl.."\\correctex}\\setlength\\lineskip{0pt}\\setlength\\prevdepth{0pt}\\leavevmode")
  local letterarray = {}
    local targetStr = mystring
-- Looping through strings require gmatch.
    for c in string.gmatch(targetStr, ".") do 
      table.insert(letterarray, c)
    end 
 local i = 0
    local itemcount = 1
  for i = 1,#value do
        if (tonumber(value[i]) >  tonumber(thresholda)) and
             (tonumber(value[i]) <  tonumber(thresholdb)) then
--    tex.sprint("\\smash{"..valchar(value[i]).."}\\hspace{0pt}")
            if #letterarray > 0 then
    tex.sprint("\\smash{"..letterarray[itemcount].."}\\hspace{0pt}")
    itemcount=itemcount+1
    if itemcount == #letterarray + 1 then
                itemcount = 1
    end
    end
    else
    tex.sprint("\\smash{".."\\ ".."}\\hspace{0pt}")
    end
  end
  tex.sprint("\\end{minipage}}")
end

--
bwascii = function ( picture )
  local file = io.open(picture, "r")
  if file==nil then
    tex.sprint("file not found")
    return
  end
  local arr = {}
  for line in file:lines() do
    if line:sub(1,1)~="#" then
      table.insert(arr,line);
    end
  end
  file:close()
  if arr[1]~="P2" then
    tex.sprint("i don't like this file")
    return
  end
  local sizes = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(arr[2],"%d+") do
    table.insert(sizes,i)
  end
  local xsize = tonumber(sizes[1])
  local ysize = tonumber(sizes[2])
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  table.remove(arr,1)
  greys = ""
  for k,v in pairs(arr) do
    greys = greys..v.." "
  end
  greys = string.gsub(greys, " +", " ")
  value = {}
  for i in string.gmatch(greys,"%d+") do
    table.insert(value, i)
  end
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\resizebox{\\textwidth}{!}{")
  tex.sprint("\\noindent\\begin{minipage}{"..xsize.."\\correctem}\\setlength\\baselineskip{1\\correctex}\\setlength\\lineskip{0pt}\\setlength\\prevdepth{0pt}\\leavevmode")
 local i = 0
  for i = 1,#value do
    tex.sprint("\\smash{"..valchar(value[i]).."}\\hspace{0pt}")
  end
  tex.sprint("\\end{minipage}}")
end
```

As to the corvid, fine detail needs high resolution, and very light shaded text will be harder to discern (although all text will be copyable).

[image: raven text]

(original engraving from Natural History of Selborne, via SciHi blog)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\directlua {require "asciiart3"}
\newcommand\bwasciitextshape[5]{\directlua{bwasciitextshape("#1",#2,#3,#4,[[#5]])}}
\newcommand\bwasciitextshade[5]{\directlua{bwasciitextshade("#1",#2,#3,#4,[[#5]])}}
\newcommand\bwascii[1]{\directlua{bwascii("#1")}}
\newcommand\colorascii[1]{\directlua{colorascii("#1")}}
\newcommand\bwframe[1]{\vspace*{\fill}\bwascii{#1}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}
\newcommand\colorframe[1]{\vspace*{\fill}\colorascii{#1}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily\frenchspacing
\newlength{\correctem}\settowidth{\correctem}{M}%to set the size of the minipage
\newlength{\correctex}\settowidth{\correctex}{x}%to set the line height
\pagestyle{empty}\centering

%\colorframe{lenna_128x128.ppm}
%\colorframe{lisa_150x224.ppm}
%\colorframe{knuth_192x227.ppm}
%\bwframe{einstein_150x206.pgm}


%----------------------------------------------------
%\bwasciitextshade{flower1.pgm}{1}{0}{256}{A flower, ...}
%\bwasciitextshade{A}              {B}{C}{D}  {E}
%               A = image filename
%                               portable gray map format (.pgm) 
%                                       create .pgm fle with, e.g., ImageMagick:
%magick convert -compress none -resize 50% flower1.png flower1.pgm
%               B = line spacing scaling factor
%                               1: aspect-ratio of image kept, but text is close together
%                               <1: squash image vertically (e.g., 0.8)
%                               >1: stretch image vertically (e.g., 1.2): easier to read text
%               C = from-value, grayscale
%                               integer, 0 (darkest) to 255 (lightest)
%               D = to-value, grayscale
%                               integer, 0 (darkest) to 255 (lightest) 
%               E = text
%----------------------------------------------------


\bwasciitextshade{raveneap.pgm}{1}{5}{240}{Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore--
    While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
"'Tis some visitor," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door--
            Only this and nothing more."

    Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December;
And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.
    Eagerly I wished the morrow;--vainly I had sought to borrow
    From my books surcease of sorrow--sorrow for the lost Lenore--
For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore--
            Nameless here for evermore.
 }


\end{document}
```

[image: negative]
[image: positive]

Answer (score 0):

### International Women's day

120 White-on-Black ASCII art

```
:~~~~~=~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,::,:~~~~~===========~~:::~::::,,,,,,,,,:::~==+++=++++++++++++++=~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~~=====~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,:,,:~~~~~=========~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::~~===+++++++++++++++~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~======~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:~~~~~=====~~~~:,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::~~===+++++++++=~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~=======~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:~~~~~~~~~~::::,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::::::~~~~~======~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
=======~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::~~::~~~::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::::::::~~::,,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~======~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::~~~::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::::::::,::,:::::~~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~=====~~~~~:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::~:~~::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,:::::::::::::::::,,::,,,:::::~~=========~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~===~~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::~~~~===+++++++++=~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
~~~~~~~~::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,:::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::III=====+++++++++++=~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
:::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,,:,:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::?III==+++===++++++=++++=:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
::::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::,,::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,??III===+=====+????????????~,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I???????~~~~===????????????????:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:???????,,,::~?????????I?II??????,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,????????,,,,,??????III????II??????:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:???????++I++?IIIIII?++?????I??????:::,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,?????+??????IIIIII??++=++?????????~~:::,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,???++++???????I???++?===++??++++?~~~~~~::,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,+??+=+++??????I??+=+======+++++++:::~~~~~~::,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,++?==+++++???????======~=====++~~~~~~~~~~~~::,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,?I+==II??~,,,,,,,,,77I~+III:,,:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,+??===++++++?????===~==~~===+=~=====~~~~~~~~::,,,,
:,,,,,,,,......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,?IIIIIIIII7IIII77IIIIIIIIIIIII:,:,,,,:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,+??+===+++++++??I=====~~~==+~~~======~~~~~~~~::,,,
::,,,,,,,.......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,IIIII7777777IIII7IIII?IIIIIII??II?:,,:,,,::::::::::::,:~+??====+++++++??====~~~~=+++++?~~~~~======~~::,,,
:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,?III77777777IIIIIIIIII?IIIIII????III=?~:::::::::::::::::~+??======++++++?????~~========++?:::~~~~~~:::,,,,
:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~??I777777IIIIIIIII???????IIII??????IIII?::::::::::::::~=~=++==============+????=========++?:::::::::,,,,,,
:::,,,,,,.........,,,,,,,,,,,,::,+?II7777IIIII?III?????+++???IIIIII???IIIII:::::::::::~+===+++==~=============+++?==+++++++?II:::::,,,,,,,,,
:::,,,,,,......,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::,+??777IIIII??III????++++++++++??III???IIII?:::,:::::+==++++===~:~=============++++++++++++???::::,,,,,,,,,,
:::,,,,,,,..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:?II77III??????+?+++=+?==?++++++??I???????III:,:::::+????+=:::::~~~~============+++++++++++???I::::::::::,,,
:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I77777IIIII??????++++==+?+I??????????????????III:~~~~?~~~~:::::~:,:~:=======+?+++?+???????+++????========~~:,,
:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,,,,,:7777777IIIII????++======??+?==+++++++++++????????II?==+======~~~~:::~~:,=======++++??+?????I+++????+++++====~~:,
:::,,,,,,,,,,,,::~=~~~:::?7777777IIII??????++=====+I?=++=~===+?+====++??I?????IIIIII+======~:~~~~:,,,,~,?+++++++?++????II+????+++++++++====~
:::,,,,,,,:~===~=~~~~~~~7777777III?I?????+++=====+???++==++~~==+?====++?????????????+======:~==~~::,,,::,,???????III???II+??+===============
:::,,,,,,~==~~~~~~~~~~~:=777IIII?????????++=====++??+?==+??+~~=+==+===++??????????++=~====::+===~~:,,,,~,,,,??I???IIII?I???+::::::::~~~~~~::
:::,,,:==+++++==~=====~:?IIIIII??+++????++=====++++?+?=++???~~++==~===++??????????++~~~~~::=====~~:::::::::::,,,,,,~III???+::::::::::::::,,,
:::,,,:=++???+??I+==+??+????IIII?+++???++++====++++++?+????+=~+=~+~~~==+??????????++~~~~~:~~==~~:::~~~~~~~~::::,,,,,:?II+:,::::::::::,,,,,,,
::,,,::::~=+????III+++II??IIIIIII??+???+++?I===+++?=+?=++++===+=~=~=~==??????????++===~~::===~::~~~~========~~::,,,,,,:,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,
,:,,,:::::~~~~?I?IIII??I?IIIIIIIIII?+??+==+?7==++++=++==========+=+~~==++++??I???++~===~:~~=~:::~====+++++++==~~:,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,
:::,,,,::~~~~~=?II?IIII?I77IIIIIIIII??++==++?7==++===+==++++?++??=~~~=++++++?????+~~~==::==~::::~==+===+=++===~~::::::,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,
::::,,,,,,,,::::~=+???II777IIIIIIIII???+==+++?I==+===+========+===~==+++++++?????+,:~=~:~=+~:::~++++=======~~~::~~~~~~~~:::,,,,:::::::::,,,,
:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~=+??IIIII??II?++===~++++I++?==+==========~~===+++++???????I,,:~::===~::~+??+====~~::::,,::~~~~~~~~~~~::,::::::::::::,
,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~???????????++===~=+++II==+???+=~~====+?+?+++?+++?????II?I,,::~++=::=+?+==+++~:,,,,,,,,,:::::~~~~~~~::,,,:::::::::~
,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:??????I???+++===~===III~++++??~?++======+++++++?????????,:~:~++=:=+++=~==~:,,,,,,,::::::::::::::::::,,,,::,,,,::~
,,::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,=??????I?+++=========??=~===========+====++++++????????,,::~==~=++=~~::::,,,,,::::~~~~~:::,,,,,,:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,:::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:=???????+++==========?+==~=============+++++???????I?:,::==~~~~::::::::::,,:::~~~~~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:++???++++=====~~===??====~=====++++++++????????I??~::~==::,,:::::::::::::::::~~~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,===+++=~~~========+=======+++++???????????????~~::~~:,:::~~~~=~~~::,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::::,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,+====~==========~======+===++?????????+??IIII,,~~:::,,::::::~~:,,,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~+++=============~====+===+++++??I?IIIII?I?I+~:~~:,,,:::,,,,,::~~:,,,,,,,:::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,??+++============~~=++++++++++?IIIIIIIII~=?::~~~~,:~:,,,,,,,,,,:~:,,,,,,::::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,????++++=========~~~~~~+??????~~=~===+====~~~~~~:~:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,??????++++++++=+============~~:~~~~~:~::::::~~~~~~=,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,.??????++++++++++++++=====+===:::~~~~~~=======~~~~=~,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~~~~~::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,??????????++++++++++++++++++=:,::~~=======~~~~~~~==:::::,,,,,,,::~====~~~:::,,,,,,,,::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,???????????+?+??+++++??++++===,,::~~~~~~~~~~=~~~~=::::~~::,,,::~~=====~~~::::,,,,:::~~~~~:,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:?????????+???+??????????+~===~~~:::::~~~~==~~~~~::::~~~::,,::~~~~~~==~~~:::::,:::~~~===~:,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~???????++?????????????:::~::~=~:~~~~=~~~~~~~~~::::::::,,:~~==~~=~===~~~::::::::::~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~+???????????+,=:,,=~:~=+=::~~~~~~~~~:,:::::::::::~===========~~~::~:::::::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,???????????,,,,,,,,,~======::~~::~~~,,,,,:::::::~~=======~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,..
,,,,,,,,:::::~~~:::::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,~?+++::,,,,,,,,,::=~======:::::=,,,,:::::::::::~~~~~~:::::::::::::::~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,::~~~~~=====~~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:,,,,:,:~=~~=~~===~:~:::~~::::::~~~~:::::::,,,,:::::::::::~~~:::,,,,,,,:~~:,,.
,,,,,,:::~~============~~::,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,::~:::~:::~~~~:~~~~~~~:::~~~~~::::::,:::::::::::::~~~~::,,....,,:~~~~:
```

Source image which is given to the generator [here](http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/) [Werner]

[image]

Comment: I guess the question was how to use that in LaTeX. There are enough ascii images to find/there are enough generators to create ones. The issue was how to include it in LaTeX.