# Holiday contest! Drawing a picture of Krampus for Yule

Tags: diagrams, fun

I've volunteered to use some of my Cthulhu reputation to sponsor a Christmas/holiday contest. You all have aced previous holiday questions, so I'm going to give you a bit more of a challenge: Draw me [Krampus, the Krampus is a beast-like creature who punishes bad children at Christmas.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus)

I'll judge the entries myself and award the one I like the most and award it a bounty of 500 reputation as the grand prize.

There are also four honourable mention categories, though they don't come with extra reputation:

1. Pure TeX. Only TeX may be used, no LaTeX, ConTeXt, Lua, etc. Extra credit if you use a really old version.
2. No fancy graphics packages; no `TikZ`, `pgf`, `PSTricks`, `pst-plot`, `Metapost`, `Asymptote`, etc. The best Krampus you can using things not designed to draw things.
3. Technical achievement; This will be voted on by a committee of volunteers from respected communities members (as I'm not qualified to judge it) and will be awarded to the most impressive use of *TeX, regardless if it is the best looking.
4. Finally, the people's choice award will go to the most upvoted submission as of the close date.

I'm going to give this a tentative date of the 21st, but that may be subject to change if I'm in transit that day, or I can't set the bounty to run that long.

The rules:

- Have fun
- You have to draw the whole thing in some member of the TeX family; no using import graphics.
- Be positive to others entries
- The goal is to have fun, so don't try and weasel around any restrictions.
- Obey Wheaton's Law
- Cthulhu Fhtagn
- I reserve the right to add more honourable mentions for stuff I find cool (Best use of LaTeX3, best animated Krampus, etc)

(Feel free to give me feedback on this contest; I've never run one before, it just seemed like a lot of fun.)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You did ask for a Christmas tree? (I updated the tree to straighten it out)

```
                                     \font
                               \t=cmtt10 at 1.5pt
                                       \t
                                 \baselineskip
                                     1.6pt
                                  \def\z#1#2{%
                              \if n#1\par\mscount0
                          \if x#2\let\z\relax\fi\else
                        \ifx\q~\def\q{X}\else\let\q~\fi
               \mscount`#1\advance\mscount-65\multiply\mscount26
     \advance\mscount`#2\advance\mscount-65 \fi\zz}\def\zz{\ifnum\mscount>0
          \q\advance\mscount-1 \expandafter\zz\else\expandafter\z\fi}
                                    \z nnnn
                                    nnnnFAA
                                 FAOAOnnFABOnn
                             FCBOnnFEAQABACAEAGACA
                         JnnFHAOABACAFABACACADABABAHnnF
                 LAZACACABAGGYAJnnFQAVABADABAHFKADBAAUnnFWBCFGA
      GBAANABAHnnGEAVDJAJBIALBAADACADACABACAInnGHANABAEDEAWAXANBCADAIACABA
HnnGJALABAFCYBJAGAVBDADALAGnnGJAEABAMCVCMBDAEAKAEnnGIAFABANCRAOABAEABBSBFARnnGIA
                                     EABAO
                               CPALACADACAVABAEAC
                       ADADAMBGAQnnGIAGACALAYAFBKAPADATAB
             AEABADAEAOBHADAGAIAEAHnnGIAGACABABAKAWAFAFAEAFACAFACAL
      APABAQABACABACABACABACABARBJAFACAYnnGIAGABABABADABAIATAGACAGAFAKALBH
 ABAGABASBLAFADAHACAJABAGnnGJANABAJAPAFACAFAFAFARAPABBNBPAFADAPABADACAInnGKAMAB
ALAGAEADAEACAFABAJARBCAHAHCBAFACAGAGADADAHACALnnGKAPABACABAKACAEABAEADAEABAHACAI
                                     AHAZC
                                   RAHADAJACA
                             EADADADAEACAJnnGLAQACA
                     QABAEACAEABAFACALAFAKADAJCTAIAEAGAFAD
             ACAGAHAFABAFnnGMAOACAKABAFACAEABBLADAICOANADAGABADAFA
    DADAKADACABAHnnGOAJAFAFABALABARAEABABAQACAKCKANAIAFACADAGADADADAEADAGAHn
nGQAIABAFADAMABBMACAKCHAKANAFACAEACBInnGSALADAHABBMABARAKADBQAJAPAGADAFABAMAJAHn
                                     nGUAS
                                  ACBIACACADAP
                          AIAEBQAHAGABAHABACAWAHAGADA
                 EnnCWAEAVAEAVACCBAOACAYABACABABACAFADARAFAHBN
       AHALACADACADAIACAEABAHAFABACAEADAEnnCWAEAUAFAUAECCBMACACABABABAEAB
AVACAJBLAHAMABACADADACACABABACADALAGADAHAEnnCVAFATAGATAFCABIACAFABACACACACBGBEAO
                                     AHABA
                                 IADAOACABAKAE
                             ADAIAEnnCUAHASAGASAGB
                          ZBKABACACACABADABBIBCAOAIACA
                     HADAGABAIACABACABAHAHADADAHnnCTAIARAD
                  ABADARAHBZBPABACABBBACAKAWAGAFAFAJACAHADAFAD
              ANACACAEAGAMnnCTAIAQADACADARAIBYAFABBHAFANADADABASAX
          AHAEAEAPACACACACACACADANACAEAEAGAGnnCTADABAEAPAEACADAQAJBYA
      JACBOADAIABAGABAKASACAEAFAFAEAQADABACADABACAEAGACADACAGAQnnCSAEABAE
  APAEACADAPAFABAEBYAIACAOAEBOABABADAGALABACARACAFALABAFABADABACACADAEAEADACA
CAHAEAFAFnnCRAEACAEAPAEABAEAOAFACAEBYAJABAJANBBACASAKBCAFACACACAEACADABACABAEAFA
                                     HADAH
                                   AEnnCQAFAC
                               AEAOAEACAEAOAEADA
                            DBYALABAFAFACALAWABAWAIA
                      KACASADACACADACABAHABABABAFAFAEADAFA
              BACAGnnCQAFACAEAOAEACAEAOAEADADBXAPADALAFAVABABABAQA
       BABAMAGAHASABAIACABAGABACACAEAFAKAKnnCQAFACAEANAFACAEANAEADAEBWAPA
DANACASACAMACAHAPAEAIBGABAEACACABABACAHAFAMnnCQAFACAEANAFACAEANAEADAEBUARADCEAOA
                                     EAJBK
                                 ACAGABAHABABAC
                         AHABAGnnCPAFADAEANAEADAEAMAEAE
                AEBTATACBIAEAQAPAFAJCCAMAGnnCPAFADAEAMAFADADANAE
       ADAFBRCFACAEABAOANAJAGCDAHAKnnCPAFADAEAMAEAEADAMAEADAFBRBYABAIACAD
ABAOALANAEAGACBKACAEABAFADACACAJnnCPAFADAEAMAEADAEALAFADAFBQAOADBGACAKACAQAKAEAC
                                     AKACA
                                     FAEBC
                                 ABAEADADABAPA
                             HAFnnCPAFACAFAMAEADAE
                         ALAEAEAFBPAOACBIABBGAEAFACASA
                     BACACBAABAEADAUAJABABADnnCPAFADAEALAE
                AEAEAKAFAEAEBPAPABBHACBPADAOABBEACADAFADABAKABA
           GAGAKnnCPAFADAFAKAEAEAEAJAFAEAFBNBXADBTADAOACBCAFAEABANAB
      AHAFAFABAEnnCPAFADAGAIAFADAFAJAFAEAEBNBRAHBSABAFACAGACADACACACAOABA
 BABAGAFAJABABACAJABAJADAEABAEnnCPAFAEAFAIAEAEAFAIAFAEAFBMDFABAZAKAUAGAEABALAB
AJABATnnCPAFAFAFAHAEAEAEAIAFAEAGBNAUACBRACATAEAPACAFABADAFANAGAFACAPABBBnnCQAEAG
                                     AEAGA
                               FAEAEAHAFAFAFBZCEA
                          BAJACAMACBKAEBEABAFACAIACAI
                   nnCQAFAFAFADAGAFAFAEAGAFAFCABBABAWACAPACBB
            ADAFACAEAGBJACASACAFnnCQAFAHALAGAFADAGAFAFCBBBABAZACANAE
      AVAEABACAEACAYACABABAJABAPACABACAOnnCRAFAHAJAHAMAGAFBZAGADAVABBAABA
   RACASADACACAPABATABAIADAIABAHACACABAEABAHnnCSAFAJADALAJAIAEBYBGACAKABADACA
HADACABBJABABAFAYABAKABAIACAGAEAFABADABABAEAKnnCTAEBMAFBZBSACAGABBNACAGADANABAM
                                     ABABA
                                BAJACAQABAMABABA
                         CAMnnCVAEBJAFCCBQACAGABADABAX
             ADALACAEACAEABAKACAKABABAEAYABADABALACAMnnCWAGBEAGCMAB
      ADAHABAQACADACADABADABAMABBDABAIACAMACABACAZACAKACANACAMnnCZAFAEAGA
QAGCLAMACARACADADADABACABALADAUABBOABAWABAHABBDnnDCALAEARCLAMACAUACAYACAGADALAB
AJADBOACALABAJABAMACAMnnDGAHAEAMCPAKACAOABAMABAWACAFACALACAIABAIABADADAWACAFACAI
                                     ACALA
                                  CAYnnDHAGAEA
                               FCXAZACADABAHACAEA
                            BAQACAFABAHABAEACAOACAGA
                         DAGACAPACBBACAOABAKnnDHAFAFAD
                      DAANABABABAJABAEADAEACBCABAHACBCADA
                 HAEAMACADACAEAEAOACADABAKACAJnnDHAEAFAEDDAJAC
             ABABAGABADACAGABBFADAVABARABAIADAHACADABAMABAOADAOACA
      JnnDHAEAFAEDDACABAGABACABAGABALABAMABATACAUACBBACAJAFAZACBCnnDHAEAF
 AEDEABABAGABACACAFACADABATACASADASABANABAQACAMACBEABAPACAHnnDHAEAFAEDAAFABAFA
CADABAGACADACARACATACARACANACAQACAJABACABANACAPACAMACAKnnDHADAGAECXAIABAEADADACA
                                     GACAV
                                 ACAPABAQACAGA
                         DAKACASABAIACBIABAJACAEABAInn
                DGAEAGAECRASACAHACAFACADACAOADAPACAGACAEACALABA
        KABALADAPABARACAQABAPABAInnDGADAHAECRAKACAFACAEABAFABAFABADACAP
 ADAOACAGACAEACAGACADACAIACANACAPABADADALADAQABAOABAJnnDGADAHAECQAKABAFABAIABAG
                                     ABADA
                                    BADABARA
                                 DANADAFABACABA
                             KACADACAIABAPACAJACAEA
                         BASABANACARABAJnnDFAEAGAFCNBC
                     ABAGACACABACABASADAHABAGACAHABAHACADA
                 CADACAHACAPACAJACAEABAEABCEnnDFAPCMATACACACAEA
            BAGACADABAUACAHACAGABAGACAIACAEACADACAGADAPADAJABAJABAL
         ADARACAXnnDFAPCJASABAFACAGABAGACACACAMACAGACAIABANABAJACAEACAE
   ACABABAEADAHABAIACAJACAIABAIACADABARACAXnnDFAMCOAOACAFABAEABADACAFABADACA
MACAQACAMABADABAFACAFABAIACAEABAHACAJABAJABAIABAIABAFACAQABAYnnDGALCJASADADACAF
                                     ABAEA
                               BAJABADABAIACARAC
                         AFABAFACADACADACAPACANACASABAY
                     ACAQABAPABAInnDFAMCGANADAFADABACAGACAE
               ADADABAGABAIABATACAFABAJACADACAQACANACASACAZABAPA
        DAOABAJnnCYATCGAGAFAOACAFADAEADAKABAGACATADAFABAJABAFABAOABAFAC
   AIADAOABAEABALABAOABALACATABAKnnCZALACALBVBEACAGACAEABALACAGACAJABAJACAGAC
AIABANABAGACAFACAIACATACALACBDACAPABALnnDABBBOBHABAIABACACALABAIACAJABAIADAGACAI
                                     ACACA
                                    BAJABAHA
                                  DAEABAJADAFA
                               BAIABAEABALACAMAC
                             APACBAnnCXBHBNATACAMA
                          BACABACAEAJABAMACAIACAJACAH
                       ABAIACABACAIACAIADADABADABAHACAFA
                    CAZABANABAQABANACALnnCVAHACBFAOABABACAFA
                 HADAPADAIACAGABABABAMAEAGABAGABAIACALABAQABABA
              CAJACAJACAHABAOACAKABANADANACBBABADABAJnnCUBLABAJABA
         IACAWAGAMACAKABALABAJABAQACBEABAKACAJACAHABAOABAMABALABARACAP
     ABAOACAKnnCUBXACBAAEBZABAQACBEABAKACAKACAGABANACAMABAEABALABANABBGABAM
 nnCSFWACBDABALABASACAMACAFABACABADABAFABALABBEABAQACAKnnCRAXACAGACAPADBOAGADAC
ACAFAPACAPABAKADAVABAHABABABAFABADABBGACAGABABACACABAIACAIACANADANABANACAMnnCSCA
                                     AFDFA
                          BAJACAFABARACAHABACABAEABAK
                ABARACAGABAGABALABANACAKACABABAPABARABADABAFnnCS
      DAAFCAABAEABAQABAHACAHACAKABAFABAKABAFABAKACAOACALADALABAOACARACALA
BABABACABAEnnCTATABACACBOADAQAEANAFAZAHACACAPABAGACAIADAJABAEACAIADAFACAJACAOABA
                                     OABAN
                                     ACANA
                        BANADADABAIABACABABABAFnnCTBKAB
                       AJAIANACASADARADAVALAEACAIABAGACAI
               ADAJABADACAIADAGACAJACAJABAUACAMABANACAHABADABAFAD
            AHABAKnnCSBJACATABANADCIALADADAGACAHACAIACAMADAIACAHACAK
    ABAJABAYABAKABARADAJACABABACABANnnCTCVAEBRAMADAIAEADAFACAHADAIACAJAFAHA
   DAIACARABABABAGABANADANABAOACALACACABAMnnCVBRABAFACAZAEBHADADAMACAJADADAFA
CAIACAUADAIAEAIACAPAEAFABAEACAZABAMABAEABABABAMABAFnnCWAMABANAPAWABBMABAEABAFBCA
                                     CAFAEA
                            CAIABAVACAKADAIADAMABAB
                        ACAHABAEADAZABARABACABAOnnCXAVB
                    BAFAGBSACABBIACAFAFADANACAIACADABAMADAH
            ACALABABABACABAKABBDABABACAOABABABAOnnDFAKCCACABBCBMABAG
AFADANACAHABAEABACABBGABABABACABANAKADACAKACARABAJnnDFAKCJADACAIAGAHBSAFACANACA
                                     HABAG
                                    AEACABA
                                   VACACADADA
                                 CAGABACAIAKADA
                               OABACABACABAOnnDFA
                            KCRAGAJAFBRASADAHACAGAD
                          ABABAMACAJABACADANADADACAJA
                         DAPABACABACABAOnnDFAKCTAHAKAEB
                       OARADAJACAGACACABADACAHABAJABADACA
                   JACAHAEAFACAPABACABASnnDFAKCXAGBZALABAFACA
              KACAHACABACACADAHABADABAEACANABAIAEAFADAHACAUnnDFAJD
          BAEBYADACAGABAFACALACAHABABACADACACACADABADABAEABAKACAKABAEA
    GAFABABABAVnnDEAKFEACADAFABAGACAKABAKABAFACABACADABACACACACAGACABABAJACA
EAHADABAYnnDEAKFFABAEADACAGABAJABAMACAEACACABAHABAIACABABABADACAPBInnDEAKFKADACA
                                     QABAM
                                     ADAIA
                                   BAOADADAOB
                              AADAQnnDEAKFLADABAP
                           ACAVABABABAGAHAEACACABASAB
                      ADABASADAGABASnnDEAKFLADACAFABACACA
                 FABBEADAJABAXADATAEAIACABABADABADnnDEAJFNACAC
             AFABADACAEABAIACACABALAHAFAFAZACAWAFAInnDEAJFNABADAFA
         BANAEAHAFABACAIACABACBEACAEABAKACAKADAJnnDEAJFRAFABAXACAJAHALA
    BBBACALACALABALnnDEAJFYAQACAEACABAEABADALABAFACAHABAJACAWACAYnnDEAJFYAMA
  DACAJAQACAFADAHACAGAEAWACAGACALABAInnDEAJFUBNACAEABAGADAHADAGAEAXACAGACAKACA
NnnDDAKFQCDADAHADAHADANACABABAHADAGACAHADARnnDDAKFMAQADANACAYADAIADAIACAZADAGACA
                                     HACAV
                                     nnDDA
                                   KFBAKABAK
                                  AHANADAKACA
                                 EABAGADAJADAKA
                               CANABALADAHACAXCIA
                             FnnDDAKFBANAKAPAEALAB
                           AEACAFADAJAEAMABBAACAIACA
                          DABATCFAEnnDDAKEVBRACANABADA
                        CATADANACARABASABAYBVACAFAEnnDDA
                      KETBSACAQACAVACAOADAMABBBABASACABBPA
                    BACADACAGnnDDAKERBSACAQACAPABAGACARABAZA
                 BAOACANABAGBOACACACACAHACACnnDCAKENARAJACABAUA
              BAPACAOADAGABBUABAMADAOACAGBLACACADABAFADACnnDBAKEKA
           SAECJADBSABAKABAIABADACAYBKACABAEABAFABADnnDBAKEIBQACBKAG
       AYABAVABAKABAIABAKACAPBLACACAOnnDBAKECBTADBKADAUADAGABAUACAEABAGA
     BAIABAKABAGABAKBIACACAIACAEnnDBAKDYANAGACABALABAKAFBAABAFACADAEAVACAHA
  CAJABAJACAEABAPACAKABAFABAEACAGBFADACAGACAFnnDBAKDXAMABAQACABABAKADBEABABAE
AEACAXACAIACAJACAHABAHABANAEAPACAMBEADACAFACAFACADnnDBAKDYAYAFAMACBGABBGACAJACAK
                                     ACAGA
                                   CAHABANAF
                                 ADACAKABANAYAB
                              AEAEACAEABAEACAEnnDB
                          AKDQBAACABAEDEACAKACAJACAHAB
                      AMACAHAGACAFABADAFABAJBBACADAFABAHAC
                   AFnnDBAKDMBAACBRADBCAFAKADALACAJACAGADAJAB
               ALARAEABAKBAACADAFABAGACAFnnDBAKDICVADAIACAQADANAD
          AOACAJACAIABAVASAEABAKAYADACANABAFnnDBAKDGATACBDABALABAKAEA
      YAEAMADARABAWABAEABARAGABAIAQAVAFACAKABAInnDBAKDEAEADAMACAZAEALAEAJ
   ADAOAEAFAEANACBQACACABADABAZAFAQAVAFACAKABAInnDBAKDIANADAKACAJABABADANADA
MACAMACAHADAZACASABARACALABAOACAEAEARANACAEAFACAKABAInnDAAKDHAMADAJAEBAAEAYACBMA
                                     CATAC
                                     ASABBG
                                    ACATAMAC
                                   AFAKACAEAC
                                 AHnnDBAJDFALA
                                 EAIAEBBAEAZACB
                                NACAHABALABASACA
                               LACADABAEACAJACACA
                             BAQANACAFAKACAEABAHADA
                           CnnDAAKDDALADAIADBEACALABA
                         PACBMADAIACAIADAKABALABAIAEACA
                      CADAEAFAFARANADAFAKABAFABAGACADnnDAA
                    KDCALACCBABABABAMADARACATAFAIADAHADAXACA
                GAGAHAMASAOAEADALACAKACADnnDAAKDBACADAGACBFABATA
            DANACAEACAMADALACAHADAJADAIADAGABACABAIACACACAGAHAHALATA
        PAGACALABAJACACnnDAAKDFBJAFAQADALACAVAEALACAIACAKADAIADAHABAGACA
   GADACABACAIACABAFAJATARBGnnDAAKDFBIADARACAMADAUABAOACAKACAJACAKACAGABAGAEA
GADAEAIACACAEAKACABAQAUANACAOnnDAAKDEAOACASADARACALADALACAIACAMADAKACAJACAKACAHA
                                     BAEAF
                                    ACABADA
                                   CAGAHAIAN
                                  AQAXANABANnn
                                DAAKDDAEABAGAEAS
                             AEARABAKADAMADAIACALA
                          DAXACASABADAHAGACACABAFAEAIA
                       NAQBEAIACAFABAFnnDAAKDCADADAFACATA
                   DAHABALABALACANACAIACAKADAXACASACACAJAGAC
             ACACAGACACABAFALASBIALABAGnnCZALDAACAEAGACAUABAHACAXA
         CAOABAHADAKADAXACAUABABAKAGADACABAFADAIAJAEABAOBMAIABAGnnCZALD
    FAGACBCACBGACAOABAKADAZABATABADAKACABAFACAEAHAGAJAEABAOBOAOnnCZALDEAGACA
KACAQADAWABAGADAEABAVACAPACAJABALAEAFABAEAJACABADABADBEAPBPANnnCZALDCASADARACAI
ACAIAGADACADALAQABAPACAQACAEAEAHABACAKADADADBCAQBSAMnnCZALDBASACARADAIABAIAHACAS
                                     AQABA
                                   PACAQADAC
                                  AFAGABADALAH
                               BBARBVALnnCZALDBAQ
                             ACASACAJABAGBEAFACAOA
                        BALACAPADACAHAHBTASBXAKnnCZALDDA
                    NADAIABAHADAHADAFBGAFABAOACAKACAQAEABCJA
           PBZAKnnCZALDBAQABAHACAIABAHADAEBKAEACAMADAJADAMABAECMAQBZ
      AKnnCZALCZBAACAOAEACBNAEABANACAJADANABAFCKAQCCAJnnCYALCXBDACAHABAFA
 FABBPACACAHABADADALACANACAGCIAQCCAKnnCYALCWACACAHACARACAGACADBYABACAGACADACAN
ACANACAICEARCDAKnnCYALCYAIACARACAHACADCBAGACADADANABAFABAIACANBYARCDAKnnCYALCWAJACARAC
                                   AIACACCDA
                                 GABAFACASABAJ
                               AFALBVASCEAKnnCYAL
                           CTALADAHABAJACAHACADCDAGAB
                      AGACARACANAEAJBTASCEALnnCYALCSACABA
                 HADAGACAKADAFAEADCEAFABAHABAKABAGACAQABAHBVAS
              CEALnnCYALCTAHADAHACASAFABCGAFABARACAGADBBBRASCEAMn
      nCXAMCQAJADAHACASCOAEACAPACAIADAYBSATCEAMnnCXAMCMAMACAGAEAFABAMCQAD
ADANADAKACALABAMBRATCEAMnnCXAMCKAWADAFACAKCTACAEAMADALADAJACANBPATCEAMnnCYALCJAC
                                     ADASA
                            DAFABAFACADCVABAFANADAKA
                     DAJACAOBNATCEAMnnCYAKCNAUADAFABAEADAC
          DDANACANACAIACAKABACBNAUCCANnnCYAKCLAIADADABAHADAEABADAEACD
FADACAHACAZAEAHBQATCBANnnCYAKCGAKAEAEACAHACADACADAEADDHACABBLADAHBOATCAAOnnCYAKC
EAKADAHACALADACAGABDJACABAPADAUACAIBMAUBYAPnnCYAKBXAPADAJACAKAEABDVAOADBFBMAUBVA
                                     QnnCY
                                     AKBVA
                                     CACAD
                             ABAIADAJACAKEDAMADBGBM
            AUBTAQnnCYAKBXANACAKADAIEGALADBCACAEBLAUBOATnnCYAKBUALAC
AKABADADAIEIALAEBBAEABBMAVBIAVnnCXALBSAMACAJACADACAKEKADACAGADAOACALBRAWBBAYnnCX
ALBSAGABAEACAJADADACAJEMACACAIACAOACALBSAWAUBBnnCXAKBSAEADAEACAGABADADADACADACAE
                                     ERAIA
                                     BAHAB
          AHACAHACADBRAYAKBGnnCXAKBRADACAFADAEADAEADAEABADABAFESACABAM
          ABAIADAHBVCLnnCXAKBNAGACAFACAEADAGAFADABACABAGEUANABAJACAHBX
          CFnnCXAKBJAJACAFACAEADAHABABACADACAKEUANACAKABAGBXCBnnCXAKBF
          ALABAHACAEACAMABADABAGADACETAQACAQBZBVnnCXAKBCAVACAEACANABAD
          ACADFBAFABAJACARCCBPnnCXAKBABDABAXFDADACAJADAPABABCEBHnnCXAK
          AXATABAMABATABACFEADABAMACAOACABCKATnnCXAKAVATACBGFJACABAMAC
          ADABAKnnCXAKAVAQADBHFJADABAHABAKABALnnCXAKAUAPADBIFKACACAHAC
 AJABANnnCXAKATAOADBIFMACACAEABADAEAGACANnnCXAJAUAMADBIFSAEABAFACAGACAEABAHnnCW
 AKATAKADBHFVADACACACACADAGACAGABAGnnCWAKBFBCGBAHACADADAGABAOnnCXAJIIAGADAEACAT
 nnCYAGIMAEADAXnnLPAFACBBnnLOBKnnLQBInnLPBInnLNBInnLKBHnnLIBEnnKMADAPBFnnKICAnn
 KHBZnnKGAHABBRnnKFAEACBTnnKDCBnnKDADABAIACBMnnKDACACAIABAOABAWnnKDACACATACAOAC
 AFnnKDACACAEADAMABAMnnKHADAFAXnnKIACAFAJACAKnnKQADAJAEnnKQADAJACnnKRACAKABnnnx
                                      \bye
```

Comment: Really cool... and somewhat scary. `:)`

Comment: Wow. That is frightening. How long did that take you?

Comment: Amazing. Could you please add some additional information how did you do it? Is it "by hand"? Amazing!

Comment: @Canageek the longest part was when I posted it the first time and the sx system said it was 40k characters and I'm only allowed 30k so I had to hand re-arrange it, shame really the first tree was nicer:-) In fairness I should reference the original image, I had not heard of Krampus before so I relied on the internet to show me what it was supposed to look like and the above is more a less a monochrome bitmap of part of this http://livraineysmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Krampus2web.jpg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So did you use a tool to convert that to TeX or did you remake the image by hand or what?

Comment: @Canageek I saved the image as a monochrome bitmap just using mspaint, then extracted that as a 0/1 array using some random online website service found by google, then just hit that with emacs editing until it looked like tex, then added random linebreaks by hand until it looked like a tree. It was half an hour or so's playing, it took much longer then to hand edit the thing to save 10K characters to fit it in the site limit:( that's when I added the catcode stuff, to save having thousands of `\ `

Comment: @Canageek I was sad the tree was distorted so I updated and used base 26 to encode the run lengths instead of base 10, so the character count is much reduced so it fits easily in the site constraints. No change in the output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Base...26.....um, never heard of that particular base being used before. Very pretty code though.

Comment: @Canageek of course you have, consider `\alph` in latex for example:-)

Answer (score 42):

I'm not a good artist, but here I leave a bust of Krampus. Drawn using a thing designed to draw things. :(

[image]

## Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\definecolor{LightGreen}{rgb}{.4,.8,.6}
\definecolor{SoftGreen}{rgb}{.2,.4,.4}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x = .25mm, y = .25mm]
        \fill[top color=LightGreen,bottom color=SoftGreen] (-10,10) rectangle (380,-340);
        \path[clip,preaction={fill=black}] plot[smooth] coordinates{(219,-330) (204,-301) (210,-290) (203,-278) (203,-271)
        (213,-274) (243,-298) (254,-322) (261,-301) (262,-289) (270,-282) (271,-276)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates{(272,-276) 
        (283,-279) (302,-293) (326,-299) (344,-290) (356,-273) (355,-254) (354,-236) (364,-230) (370,-230) (365,-223)
        (351,-223) (342,-229) (338,-242) (339,-258) (334,-272) (316,-273) (305,-263) (296,-255) (289,-251) (283,-250)} --
        plot[smooth] coordinates{(283,-248) (283,-242) (276,-235) (281,-234) (290,-239) (300,-239) (302,-229) (296,-219)
        (291,-198) (283,-190) (276,-186) (273,-182) (280,-179) (286,-172) (284,-160) (276,-156) (266,-145) (259,-138)
        (254,-129) (254,-115) (255,-109) (251,-107)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates{(249,-103) (217,-46) (168,-13) (109,-3)
        (67,-32) (30,-78) (3,-134) (0,-171) (6,-177) (10,-160) (35,-122) (73,-81) (127,-70) (159,-90) (170,-111)} --
        plot[smooth] coordinates{(165,-112) (156,-113) (146,-117) (135,-120) (121,-118) (114,-117) (98,-118) (88,-121)
        (78,-121) (68,-126) (66,-129) (79,-134) (88,-140) (100,-152) (109,-158) (118,-162) (115,-172) (108,-179) (97,-188)
        (87,-200) (73,-218) (82,-214) (78,-222) (66,-238) (77,-234) (69,-243) (61,-260) (75,-249) (66,-261) (57,-274)
        (66,-267) (50,-291) (56,-288) (49,-311) (43,-330)} -- cycle;
        \fill[left color=black, right color=red] plot[smooth] coordinates{(282,-249) (280,-278) (289,-308) (340,-315)
        (369,-263) (373,-233) (353,-198) (327,-237) (295,-247)} -- cycle;
        \fill[white] (264,-181) circle (2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that is not impressive like David Carlisle's answer, but I had so much fun. :D

Comment: This is a great picture and I wish I understood any package well enough to do this (whether designed to draw things or not). But it is not an answer to the question, is it? Since it uses something explicitly prohibited, albeit to very good effect...

Comment: @cfr Use TikZ is not prohibited, only an honorable mention is not obtained... I think. :)

Comment: Oops. You're right. My mistake. Sorry. You are just disqualified from 2 honourable mentions, I think! I think you could still qualify for the other 2, in fact, now I read it properly.

Comment: Exactly. I was expecting lots of entries, I just wanted to see what could be done without it. Did you design this yourself or base it off another image?

Comment: @Canageek I was expecting too, especially to learn a lot (I could not do it with the Carlisle's answer, hahaha). I saw the silhouette in a concert poster (link missed), crop the image and create a HTML app to extract pixels positions by clicking, corrected a few things, and I've colored.

Answer (score 10):

ASCII Krampus, run with `xetex`. I used [an image I found via Google image search as the base](http://www.theaustrianrestaurant.com/userimages/krampus_16.jpg).

```
\special{background rgb  .25 .15 .14}
\def\mainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\hoffset=-1in
\font\tenrm="\mainfont:color=A28367" \rm
\font\red="\mainfont:color=FD482F"
\catcode`\R=13
\def R#1{{\ \ \red #1}\ }
\offinterlineskip
\obeylines\obeyspaces\let =\ 

                                                            R{▁▂▅}
                                                         R{▖▄██▛}
            R{▜█▙▖}            ▗▄▅▆▇████████▇▆▅▄▃▂▁    R{▟███▘}
              R{▜███▙}     ▁▟███████████████████████▙ R{▟███▛}
                R{████▛ }  ▜████████████████████████R{█████▊} 
                 R{▔▀▀▀▀▔▗▙}▐█████████████████████R{▄▂▁▁▂▄▖}
                   R{▆▆▆▇██▊ }▀▜█████████████████R{░▔▀█▛▀▘}░▗
                 ▟██▙R{▔▔▔▔▁▗▘░░}▜██████████████R{░▟▆▃▂▄▖}████▙
          ▗█    ▆█████R{▜█▛▀▘░░▗▖░}▜██████████▛R{░░▀▀▀▀▘}███████▖    ▗▖
         ▗██▌  ▟███████▙R{▁▁▁▂▅██░░}▗▅▃▂▁▔▁▂▃▄R{▝██▆▅▆▇ }████▇▇▇▇▖  ▗█▋
        ▟█▛▜▊ ▐█████████▙R{▔▀█▛▀▔ ▖}▐████████▛R{▖░▝▀▀▀▘}██████████ ▟██▋
       ▟██▚██▙▜█████▀▀▀▀▔R{▔▜▃▄▅▇▘▝}▄▅▆▆▆▆▆▆▆▖R{█▙▃▄▞▝} ██████▜▚▞▘ ██ ▐
       ██▊▐███▐███▛▗▇██████▙▃▂▁▁▂▃▁ ▀▀█████▀▀▔ R{▔▔▔}  ▟▆▆▅▆▅▖     █▋ ▟
       █▉ ▐░██ ▊▛ ▟█▛▀▔▔▔▀████████████▇▆▅▅▆▇█████▇▆▆▇███▙▆█▇▆▖     █▍▐▋
       ▐▋ ▐░▍▐▎▐ ▟▛▔  ▁▂▁   ▜████▛▀▀▀███████▘▀▚▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▔         █ █▉
       ▕▌ ▐░▍▐▋ ▟█  ▟█████▙▂          ████▛           ▗▅▄▅▆▇██▙  ▚ ▌▐█▛
        █ ░░▌▐█ ▓▋░▐█▛▘▔ ▔▀▀▀▀▚▝        ▁             ▔▔▔▔▀▜██▊  █ ▋▐█▌
        ▜ ░█▘ ▜ ▓▊▓▝▔  ▗▗▅▀▔       ▚▗  ▞█▚          ▔▀▀▀█▖       █ ▘▕██
        ▕ █▛    ▓█    ▟▘▔ ▗░░░░▖      ▐███▋    ▗▟▘▘▗░░░▖         █   ▜█
         ▐█     ▓█▙▁▂▛    ▋░▜▛░░▍  ▗  ▟███▙   ▟▛  ▐░▜▛░░▎        ▐    █▎
         ▐▊     ▓█████▙   ▝▚░░▞▘    ▟██▀▔██  ▝▃▅▁  ▝░░░▀      ▟█ ▐▌   █▎
         ▕▋    ▟▓█████▙   ▃▂▁▁▂▃▖ ▁▟██▊▓▓██   ▜█▙            ▟██ ▐▋  ▕█
          ▜▖   ▓▓██████▙▖ ▜█▀▘▔▁▞█████▋▓▓██    ▜██▙▖▁▁▁▁▁▄▖▟████ ▐▌  ▟▛
           ▜▙▖ ▐▓▓███████▙▄▄▅▇████████▌▓▓██  ▚▞ ▜█████████████▛  ▟   ▟
            ▜█▌▝▓▓▓███████████████████▍▓▓██  ▖▚ ▕███████████▚▚▚  ▉ ▗▞
             ██ ▐▓▓▚██████████████▛▀▔▀▘▓▓██▍ ▗▖▙ ▐██████████▞▞▞ ▟▌▕█▎
             ▜█▙ ▘▓██████████████▛ ▟██ ▓▓██▋ ▐██▙ ▜██████████▞▞▝░ ▐▋
              ▜█▍ ▚▓▓▜██████████▛ ▟███▓▓▓▜██ ▞▛▀▔ ▐██████████▛▓▓  ▐
               ▜  ▕ ▓▓▚████████▛  ▀▘▝█▖▓▓▓▜█▍▘  ▟▙ ▜████████▛▓▓  ▟
                     ▓▓▜██████▐ ▝███▄▖▝▆▄▟█▛▝  ▟██▙ ▜██████▐▓▓ ▟
                      ▓▓██████▎ ▟█████▙▂▁ ▁▂▃▄▆████▋ ▐███▚▚▖▞▞
                       ▓▜█████  ███████▀▀▀▀▀▀██████▋ ▐█████▌▓▞
                        ▓▜████  █▛▀▘            ▔▀██  █████▛▓
                         ▓████     R{▗   ▗   ▗}    ▝  ████▘▓
                          ▓▜█▉ R{▙ ▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▓▓▓▓▙▟}     ▜█▛▘▓▓
                           ▓██▖ R{░▓▒░░░░░░░░░▒▓}   ▟▌▕▛▓▓▓
                           ░▐██▖ R{░░░▒▒░░░▒▒░░░}   ██ ▌▒▒
                            ▟███▖ R{▓████░████▓░}  ▟██ ░░░
                             ▚███ R{█████░█████▓} ▟██▍ ░
                               ▚█ R{█████░█████▓} ▛ ▘
                                ▐▋R{█████░████▊▓}    ░░
                                  R{█████░████▊▓}   ░░░
                                  R{▜████░████▊▓}
                                   R{█████████▌▓}
                                   R{█████████▌▓}
                                   R{█████████▌▓}
                                   R{▜████████▋▓}
                                   R{▐████████▛} 
                                    R{████████▛}
                                     R{▜█████▛}
                                      R{█████}
                                       R{▜██▘}
                                        R{▀▘}


\bye
```

Comment: Menlo is not available in non-Mac operating systems.

Comment: `\def\mainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}`
should produce [basically the same output](http://9-bits.com/post/123940811/menlo-font-macosx)