# TikZ: How can I write my code more concisely?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, code-review

I am learning how to use TikZ and want to learn ways to write more concise TikZ code. I feel I use many more lines than others may need to achieve the same results.  In particular, I want to learn a technique or practice for writing concise code that I can use for all my TikZ documents.

As an example, consider this image:

[image]

… which was created with the code below (the spacing is supplied for readability). Note that you may have to update TikZ and pgf to run this code, as the `angles` and `quotes` libraries are relatively new as of May 2014.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3, 0);
  \coordinate (C) at (3, 2);

  \draw[name path = tri] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle pic["$\alpha$", -stealth,
  draw, angle radius = 1cm, angle eccentricity = 1.25] {angle = B--A--C};

  \path[name path = line] (0, 1.4) -- +(2.9, 0);
  \path[name intersections = {of = line and tri, by = P1}];

  \path (P1) -- ($(P1)!.25cm!-90:(A)$) coordinate (cylinder);
  \path[name path = line2] (cylinder) -- +(1.05, 0);
  \path[name intersections = {of = line2 and tri}];

  \draw (cylinder) circle[radius = 0.25cm];
  \draw[dashed, gray] (cylinder) -- (intersection-1);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (3.15, 2) -- ($(intersection-1) + (.15, 0)$);
  \draw (3.1, 2) -- (3.2, 2);
  \draw ($(intersection-1) + (.1, 0)$) -- +(.1, 0);
  \draw (cylinder) -- +(45:.25);

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{atan(2/3)};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ppi}{\angle + 180}

  \begin{scope}[rotate = \angle]
    \clip ($(cylinder) + (0, .4)$) rectangle ($(cylinder) + (-.4, 0)$);

    \draw[name path global = rotation] (cylinder) circle[radius = .395cm];
  \end{scope}

  \path[name path = line3] (cylinder) -- +(\ppi:.4);
  \path[name intersections = {of = line3 and rotation, by = P2}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Code-review questions are not really on topic here. Unless you have a specific problem with a specific part of the code, I'm tempted to vote to close your question as "too broad".

Comment: @Jubobs I re-read what question are okay and not okay section.  From my reading, I don't see a problem with it. This invites sharing experiences over opinions and this is a question about how (these two come from the not okay section under some subjective are okay).

Comment: fwiw, I think your question is fine, and on topic - I feel like you'll be unlucky to get it closed

Comment: @dustin: You are using a number of practices that make your code more readable and more robust, at the expense of being a bit longer. For instance, you have lots of spaces and skipped lines that are not strictly necessary. You also describe a number of paths and coordinates in terms of previously defined things. If you were to eliminate the unnecessary spaces and give explicit, hand-computed coordinates for everything (and eliminate all your names), your code would be significantly shorter; but I urge you not to do so.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I am not considering line spacing in my question.  I add this in for readability only.

Comment: That having been said, you can probably get some mileage out of stringing together disjoint paths in one command, e.g., `\path (0,0) \coordinate(A) (3,0) \coordinate(B) (3,2) \coordinate(C);`. Note that I have not checked to make sure that actually works, but I know similar things are possible.

Comment: Dustin, I've supplied an edit that takes into account all of the negative feedback you've had, and tries to provide an example of how you could structure this so that your question is clearer. I also up voted it as I feel like it's more worth keeping. If you'd like to delete your comments to my (now deleted) comments, we can tidy up this thread.

Comment: Related Meta Thread http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/tagging-please-improve-my-code-posts

Comment: @AndyClifton I think that the recent answers show it is still not a suitable question for this site. In particular, I see no way it could help other visitors. The request for improvement should be more concrete, like "how can I condense all the draw commands".

Comment: To the OP: Could you explain what is the aim of your quest for conciseness: Are you concerned with performance, or reuseability, or do you wish to type less?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some shortening without the angle arrow. But that can be done with `angle` library anyway. Changing the angle is possible.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myang{35}
\draw (0,0) coordinate(o) --+(\myang:1cm) +(1,0)arc (0:\myang:1cm)
      node[right,midway]{$\alpha$}--(\myang:3cm) coordinate (a) 
      node[minimum size=5mm,circle,draw,pos=0.4,anchor={-90+\myang}] (b) {}--(o-|a)
     (b.center)--(b.\myang) (b.210)++(210:1mm) arc (210:120:3.5mm);
\draw[dashed] (b.center) -- (a|-b);
\draw[>=latex,|<->|] ([xshift=2mm]a|-b) -- ([xshift=2mm]a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can save one more keystroke by removing `%` right after `{standalone}`.

Comment: @IamwhoIsayIam I can save a lot by removing all the spaces and make a one liner.

Comment: Can you explain this piece `node[minimum size=5mm,circle,draw,pos=0.4,anchor={-90+\myang}] (b) {}--(o-|a)
     (b.center)--(b.\myang) (b.210)++(210:1mm) arc (210:120:3.5mm);`?

Comment: @dustin I'm placing a node on the 40% of the path lenght via pos key and I'm anchoring by it's point where it touches the inclined path via `anchor` key and name it as `b`. Then I continue to draw to the orthogonal intersection of o and a. Then I move the pen to `b.center` and draw the radius mark. Then I move again the pen to b.210 and give 1mm offset to draw the motion arc around it. I adjust the radius to 3.5 mm since the radius of the ball is 2.5mm from `minimum size` + 1mm offset.

Answer (score 16):

This is more concise (and no less readable than most tikz code:-)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,
angles,quotes}\def\c{\coordinate}\def\d{\draw}\def\p{\path}
\def\pp#1#2#3#4#5{\p[name path=#1](#2)--+(#3);\p[name intersections={of=#1
and #4,#5}];}\let\q\pgfmathsetmacro
\begin{document}\def\z#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{\begin{tikzpicture}
\c(A)at(0,0);\c(B)at(3,0);\c(C)at(3,2);\d[name path=#7](A#6(B#6(C#6cycle
pic["$\alpha$",-#3,draw,#1 #4=1cm,#1 eccen#7city=1.25]{#1=B--A--C};\pp
{#8}{0,1.4}{2.9,0}{#7}{by=P1}\p(P1#6($(P1)!.25cm!-90:(A)$)coordinate(#2);
\pp{#82}{#2}{1.05,0}{#7}{}\d(#2)circle[#4=0.25cm];\d[dashed,gray](#2#6(#5-1);
\d[#3-#3](3.15,2#6($(#5-1)+(.15,0)$);\d(3.1,2#6(3.2,2);\d($(#5-1)+(.1,0)$#6+
(.1,0);\d(#2#6+(45:.25);\q{\angle}{atan(2/3)};\q{\ppi}{\angle+180}\begin
{scope}[rotate=\angle]\clip($(#2)+(0,.4)$)rect#1($(#2)+(-.4,0)$);
\d[name path global=rotation](#2)circle[#4=.395cm];\end{scope}\pp{#83}{#2}
{\ppi:.4}{rotation}{by=P2}\end{tikzpicture}}\z{angle}{cylinder}{stealth}
{radius}{intersection}{)--}{tri}{line}\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX.SX users, beware! Obfuscating troll on the loose!

Comment: So true!   And that comment is @David, not at Jubobs.

Comment: @Jubobs "troll" what a thing to say:-)

Comment: @Jubobs Note that this is not really obfuscation, it is a demonstration of what happens if you apply the common programming practice of making things concise by parametrising to remove  duplicate code to a _macro_ language like TeX. So `tri` only gets entered once and used as `{tri}` and `eccen tri city`. To TeX, that is no different from taking any common code out of a loop. So it is a demonstration by taking to extremes that "more concise" probably shouldn't be a design goal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, it's more akin to a combination of *optimisation taken to the extreme* and *minification*, but I maintain that *troll* applies here `:p`

Comment: @Jubobs At least it doesn't make a [Krampus jump out at you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149616/1090)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nice! I had overlooked that answer of yours.

Answer (score 8):

It is still too short in an animation.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    CurveType=polygon,
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
    LabelSep=.5,
    MarkAngleRadius=1,
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=3.14+.10}{50}{%
\begin{pspicture}(8,6)
    \pstGeonode{A}(7,0){B}(7,6){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[arrows=->]{B}{A}{C}{$\alpha$}
    \pnode([offset=.5,nodesep=\n]{C}A){P}
    \pscircle(P){.5}
    \rput{(C)}(P){\psarc(P){.6}{90}{180}\psline(P)([nodesep=.5,angle={!\n\space 4 mul Pi add 2 div neg RadtoDeg}]P)}
    \pcline[offset=.5]{|*-|*}(C)(C|P)
    \pcline[linestyle=dashed,nodesepB=-.5](P)(C|P)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: (+1) I'm sorry, I just… have to know… I don't know PSTricks, but I need to know if the turning radius line touches the top of the triangle there. For science (and mild obsessive-compulsive tendencies).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Is it a question or a statement?

Comment: Question. :) It looks like it should.

Comment: @SeanAllred: The rotating radius line will reach the top point of the triangle if and only if a certain condition is satisfied. The condition is the length of the hypotenuse must be an integer multiple of the wheel circumference.